# Regex code for finding a URL containing and domain and adding a parameter

Tags: regex

Help! Needed for wordpress search and replace

Have a bunch of links to amazon.com/productname/dp/productid or similar.

Want to have a regex code that will search any URLs that contain amazon.com and end of the URL add the following "?tag=tagname"

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

Search: `(<a[^<>]*href=["']amazon.com.*?)(?=["'])`
Replace: `$0?tag=tagname`

It basically looks for anything that start with `<a`, then tests if some characters are present or not. Finally it adds the addition, `?tag=tagname`, before the closing `"` or `'`.

Assuming you're using PHP:

```
$re = '/(<a[^<>]*href=["\']amazon.com.*?)(?=["\'])/';
$str = '<a data-foo="href=\'amazon.com/\'" href=\'amazon.com/productname/dp/productid\' data-foo2=\'bar\'/>';
$subst = '$0?tag=tagname';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo "The result of the substitution is ".$result;
```

I am not sure why it's not capturing the `data-foo="href='amazon.com/'"` though, but works as required.

Comment: I'm trying this regex code in Atom editor, and it says invalid regex code.